# How to remove elements inside div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to remove elements inside div using javascript ?

I tried to remove all element inside div `id="myList_2"`

But not work , How can i do that ?

THANK YOU FOR ALL..

http://jsfiddle.net/tr8ack7v/1/

```
<div id="myList_1">
    <span id="x">111111</span>
</div>
<div id="myList_2">
    <span id="x">222222</span>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(data_value) {
    var list = document.getElementById("myList_"+data_value);
    var x_child=document.getElementById("x");
    list.removeChild(x_child);                                 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#myList_2 #x').remove()`

Comment: HTML ID should be **unique**. If you have several elements with the same ID, then you will have **many** problems - for example, not able to select all items with selector. You need to give your elements unique IDS. You can also simply empty `myList_2` using `$("#myList_2 #x").empty()`.

Comment: could you please use `var data_value` on comments

Answer (score 1):

Here you go -  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8ack7v/8/)

Don't reuse `id`s on html elements. An `id` should be unique, use `class` instead.

```js
var a = $('#myList_1 > .x');

$('button').click(function(){
 $(a).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList_1">
    <span class="x">111111</span>
</div>
<div id="myList_2">
    <span class="x">222222</span>
</div>
<button>Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate `"x"` `id`s at `span` elements ? Try adding `"1"` , `"2"` , respectively , to `span` `id` property to substitute unique `id`s in document for duplicate `id` s at `span` elements

```html
<div id="myList_1">
  <span id="x1">111111</span>
</div>
<div id="myList_2">
  <span id="x2">222222</span>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction(data_value) {
    var list = document.getElementById("myList_" + data_value);
    var x_child = document.getElementById("x" + data_value);
    list.removeChild(x_child);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `id`s that are the same, `id`s should be unique.

Here is a version that uses classes instead (which dont have to be unique):

```
<div id="myList_1">
    <span class="x">111111</span>
</div>
<div id="myList_2">
    <span class="x">222222</span>
</div>
<button onclick="javascript: myFunction(2)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(data_value) {
    var list = document.getElementById("myList_"+data_value);
    var x_child=list.getElementsByClassName("x")[0];
    list.removeChild(x_child);                                 
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8ack7v/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myList_1">
  <span id="x1">111111</span>
</div>
<div id="myList_2">
  <span id="x">222222</span>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(data_value) {
  var list = document.getElementById("myList_"+data_value);
  var x_child=document.getElementById("x");
  list.find('#x').remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#myList_2").innerHTML = ''
```

should work, haven't tried it, but it works to get rid of paragraphs for me

Comment: please verify your answers and use comments for such small answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).